# JSON to Initialize Data in Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a small AngularJS app and I'm currently struggling with creating a service.

I have a service that serves as a backend for providing contacts (name, address...). 
Until now they were hard-coded as an array in the service (`instance.contacts=[...]`), but now I'm trying to read them from a json file :

```
myModule.factory('contactService', ['$http',function ($http) {
    var instance = {};

    $http.get('contacts.json').success(function (data) {
        instance.contacts = data;
    });

    return instance;
}]);
```

**I see in my browser console that the file has been read successfully, but I don't see any change on-screen.**

So I tried the following instead, and it worked :

```
myModule.factory('contactService', ['$http',function ($http) {
    var instance = {
        contacts:[]
    };

    $http.get('contacts.json').success(function (data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
            instance.contacts.push(item);
        });
    });

    return instance;
}]);
```

I don't know why the second code snippet works, and not the first. Could someone please help me understand ?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code? Where are you accessing it? `$http` returns a promise, but I don't see your service returning *anything*.

Comment: Sorry, this is only a snippet, and I removed the "return instance" part inadvertantly. I'll put it back.

Comment: The `return instance` is actually what's broken. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$http` is asynchronous, so you can't return an array because when you return it, it probably doesn't have any data in it yet. You actually have to return the promise:

```js
var instance = $http('contacts.json');

return instance;
```

And then in your controller (or in another service):

```js
contactService.then(function(response) {
  $scope.contacts = response.data;
});
```

Just remember that no matter where you access your service, you must interact with it as a promise using `then`.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll just split between the generic service and the `$http` access...

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using `ngResource`, in which case your code should look something like this:

```
myModule.factory('contactService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('contacts.json', {}, {
        get: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
})
```

Ensure that myModule has `ngResource` in its list of dependencies.  Then within your controller you can access the data with `contactService.get()`

Comment: I recommend against using `ngResource` if the server-side API isn't restful - it can cause a lot of headaches. But if it is, it's great!

Comment: True, I just assume that everything is RESTful nowadays!

Comment: I cannot return a $resource directly, because my service has other methods (saveContact(), getContactById(), etc.). My goal is to pre-load a dataset in an array, nothing more - I don't have a restful server (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a full example, here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/VsuAKNavPbHL7RWbrvKD?p=preview. The idea followed is just the same as metioned by Josh David Miller.