# Angular.bootstrap() and logging

Tags: angularjs

Thank you for looking at this,

We recently acquired a project that uses angular 1.x and we're making modifications to the application slowly. However, we noticed that we can't get any logging methods to work when using `angular.bootstrap()` to start up the application. This also seems to effect other functions on the window object. However, no issue like this exists when bootstrapping with the ng-app directive.

**A running code snippet demonstrating this issue can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kCx6k5oaZ59FSQxqBhBW)**
I'm expecting the console to have hello 1, hello 2, and hello 3 to be printed along with anything in the message input when I click one of the log buttons. I've also included an alert box to demonstrate that the problem isn't limited to logging. However

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-example110-production</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="LogController">
        <p>Reload this page with open console, enter text and hit the log button...</p>
        <label>Message:
            <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
        </label>
        <button ng-click="alert()">alert</button>
        <button ng-click="$log.log(message)">log</button>
        <button ng-click="$log.warn(message)">warn</button>
        <button ng-click="$log.info(message)">info</button>
        <button ng-click="$log.error(message)">error</button>
        <button ng-click="$log.debug(message)">debug</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### script.js

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('hello1')
    angular.module('logExample', []);
    angular.module('logExample')
        .controller('LogController', ['$window', '$scope', '$log', function ($window, $scope, $log) {
            $scope.$log = $log;
            $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
            $log.log('hello2');
            $window.console.log('hello3')
            $scope.alert = function () {
                $window.alert('hi')
            }
        }]);
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['logExample']);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: hope below solution helped you. Please mark as accepted if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose you bootstrap within document.ready, if you setup your scripts as you have done.

```
   angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['logExample']);
})
```

Otherwise, you need to load your scripts at the end of your page.

Working plunker :

http://plnkr.co/edit/LZDjnAGMlU3Npoetdg2U?p=preview

Please refer this answer for more details . There are multiple ways of doing this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16539428/6347317

Comment: Thank you! The included reference is a well appreciated bonus.