# Making an Angular filter using $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-filters

I'd like to do an `$http` `get` request and return the result to the front-end. On the front-end, I use `{{ URL-STRING | iframely }}`.

```
'use strict'

angular.module( 'iframely', [] ).filter( 'iframely', [ '$http', function ( $http ) {
    return function ( url ) {

        var result = $http( {
            url: 'http://localhost:8061/iframely',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                url: url
            }
        })

        return( result.then( function ( result ) {
            console.log( result.data.html )
            return result.data.html
        }))
    }
}])
```

The result is on the front-end I just get `{}` (looks like an empty object). But my console log shows the desired HTML.

I'm pretty sure the general set-up is right because if I just do `return "it works"` in there, that works. I think the problem is something about JS scoping, returns or `$http` that I'm not getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronously initialize AngularJS filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046641/asynchronously-initialize-angularjs-filter)

Comment: @ShayFriedman Can you explain why you think this is a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noah,

The expression is being resolved to `{}` because the object you are returning in the filter definition is empty in fact. You are returning a promise and AngularJS is just printing the returned object in your HTML - not the resolved value as you probably expect.

You are using AngularJS filters in an inappropriate way in this case. In order to get the functionality you want, you should create a directive instead. You could use the directive in the following way in your HTML:

```
<iframely url="{{ URL-STRING }}"></iframely>
```

And implement it with the following code:

```
angular
    .module('app', [] )
    .directive('iframely', ['$http', '$sce', function ($http, $sce) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                url: '@'
            },
            template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $http({
                    url: attrs.url,
                    method: 'GET'
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(result.data.html);
                });
            }
    };
}]);
```

Valeu!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<iframely url="{{ URL-STRING }}"></iframely>` or something. How does the URL get piped in?

Comment: Yes. You can substitute `/content/data.html` by `{{variable}}`.

Comment: I've submitted an edit for your post that makes that work. Will mark correct when edit is accepted.