# Return data from Asynchronous callback in AngularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-filter

The scenario is that I was using a simple filter in my application to crop images like this - 
HTML -

```
<img ng-if="item.data.topImage" ng-src="{{item.data.topImage | cropImage:240:135}}">
```

Original Filter -

```
.filter('cropImage', [function () {
        return function (url, width, height, noDefault) {
            return cropImage(url, {
                width: width,
                height: height
            });
        };
    }])
```

This `cropImage` was a simple function.
Now I want to call a function which uses asynchronous callback.
Now the updated filter is like this -

Updated Filter -

```
.filter('cropImage', [function ($q) {
        return function (url, width, height, noDefault) {
                    var defered = $q.defer();
            buildfire.imageLib.local.cropImage(url, {
                width: width,
                height: height
            }, function (e, d) {
                if (e)
                    defered.reject('');
                else {
                    defered.resolve(d);
                }
            });
            return defered.promise;
        };
    }])
```

But this fails,as expected.

What can I do in this case. I know I can use a directive, but this filter is used throughout my application. What else I can do except $timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with `img` element and want to prevent requests until the image url has not been created, you should really look into a directive that does all this, because I think that is the best way to go.

If filter is what you want, You need to look into [`$stateful`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/docs/guide/filter)  filters, which will allow us to return an initial value until we have completed the async operation and then update with the final value, since after `v1.3x` the filters will not be called if you return an initial value and until the value is changed.

For a detailed explanation you can have a look at this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046641/angularjs-asynchronously-initialize-filter#27771259).