# How can I change a value inside of ng-repeat after the repeat complete?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON which provides me a user's working experiences info. But country and city's are provided in a code format (TR,DE etc.)
I am using ng-repeat to pass them into html like this

```
<div ng-repeat="e in experiences">
   <span>{{e.Name}}</span>
   <span ng-init="changeCodeToFullName(e.Country)">{{vm.CountryFullName[$index]}}</span>
</div>
```

I am using ng-init to convert Country Code to full name. changeCodeToFullName is an angular service written by me, Is this a correct method? If it is, I can't access the dom to change CountryFullName value. I tried to access them in JS file like `vm.CountryFullName[0]="TEST"` but it didn't worked. I need to use e.Country variable after, therefore I can't change the original .e.Country value.

How can I access a variable inside of ng-repeat after ng-repeat completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a custom [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter):

```
<div ng-repeat="e in experiences">
    <span>{{e.Name}}</span>
    <span>{{e.Country | changeCodeToFullName}}</span>
</div>

angular.module('App').filter('changeCodeToFullName', function(YourService) {
    return function(country) {
        return YourService.getFullCountryName(country)
    }
})
```

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/rustydev/pen/YWyqJB

Comment: I have tried filter but I see {} in html. My filter code is this: `app.filter('changeCountryCodeToFullName', function(testService) {
    return function(countryCode) {
        return testService.getCountryName(countryCode)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(222,result);
            return result;
        })
    }
})
` I can see the result in console.

Comment: My service is using $q promise. Because I am getting these datas with a web API. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046641/angularjs-asynchronously-initialize-filter

Comment: I have watched this https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-stateful-filters-with-promises-in-angularjs and I solve the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it - but this `ngInit` value won't be reparsed if the list updates. Why not just format the data in the JSON request response - such as:

```
$http.get("json.json").success(function(data) {
    $scope.exeriences = data.map(function(obj) {
        //Format results;
        if (obj.Country == "DE") {
            obj.Country = "Germany"; //etc
        }
        return obj;
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't because list is too long. I have to do it dynamically. I have another service to change code to full name. I want to use this service and list won't be updated dynamically.