# Use promise with angularjs user filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angularjs-filter

I have a user filter. You can see the mock example below (it returns the same data which it gets, i.e. users_data_contents, in reality there is the function call):

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', [])
    .filter('filter_ghosts', function($rootScope){
        return function(users_data_contents){ // gets data from view
            return users_data_contents;
        };
    });
```

I need to use it in async mode, but not quite understand how. I tried something like this:

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', [])
    .filter('filter_ghosts', function($rootScope){    
        function getPromised(){
            var cnt = 0, intrv = setInterval(function() {
                ++cnt;
                if (cnt>10) {
                    return function(users_data_contents){
                        clearInterval(intrv);
                        return users_data_contents;
                    }
                }
                if (cnt > 50) {
                    clearInterval(intrv);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        getPromised.$stateful = true;
        return getPromised;
    });
```

But this doesn't work. 
The html where the filter is applied looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user_data in usersList | filter_ghosts">
    ....
```

### Can anybody help?

### UPD

The most close solution to my issue is here: [AngularJS : Asynchronously initialize filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046641/angularjs-asynchronously-initialize-filter)
However, it is turned out that the more appropriate approach is not to use filter at all but bind the repeater to array which is changed on corresponding procedures.

Comment: I don't think that filters support promises. What you'll have to do is create a service instead. And call that

Comment: `getPromised` does not get anything at all.  It has no return statement.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by `async mode`.  I can't figure out what you are trying at achieve.  Do you mean you want to return a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty array in the scope. Then bind your `ng-repeat` with filter to that array. Then just fill that array with the values when your async operation completes.