# AngularJS filter with a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm upgrading a filter from a static object to an object retrieved from our database, but I can't seem to get a proper return. This filter takes in an integer which represents a named location, it looks up the location with the key, and returns the name. After troubleshooting, I'm getting close as I can see the object from the database and I can see some of the lookups correctly inside of the then section, but it's not being returned at the end of the filter. Is there a better method on getting this with a filter?

**stPartFieldFilters.js**

```
angular.module('app').filter('partLocation', function(stPartMgmtSvc, $q) {
  var locs;
  function getLocations() {
    if(!locs) {
      var dfd = $q.defer();
      stPartMgmtSvc.getLocations().then(function(res) { locs = res; dfd.resolve(locs); }, function(response) { dfd.reject(response.data.reason) });
      return dfd.promise;
    }
    else {
      var dfd = $q.defer();
      dfd.resolve(locs);
      return dfd.promise;
    }
  }

  function getResults(loc, type) {
    var lr = null; // this should be updated once a match is found below
    getLocations().then(function(ls) {
      if (loc || loc === 0) {
        loc = loc.split(',');
        if(typeof loc === 'object') {
          var res = new Array;
          loc.forEach(function(l) {
            res.push(ls[l].name)
          });
          if(!type) { lr = res.toString().replace(',', '<br>'); } // this line provides the correct output; see below (LOCFLTRRES1)
          else { lr = res.toString().replace(',', ', '); }
        }
        else { lr = ls[loc].name; }
      }
      else { lr = false; }; 
    });

    return lr; // return the updated result
  }

  return function(loc, type) {
    return getResults(loc, type); //return the final result for the filter
  }
});
```

**inventory.jade**

```
~~~
td.desktop-only {{part.partLoc | partLocation:1}}
~~~
```

Here is an image of the results of the database object.
[image: Database object]

Here is an image of the result inside of the filter. This should be set to lr and returned to the main filter function.
[image: Map result]

Here is the expected result.

[image: Expected result]

Finally, here is the actual result.

[image: Actual result]

Comment: A filter needs to be synchronous. You can't pass a promise to the view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AngularJS : Asynchronously initialize filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046641/angularjs-asynchronously-initialize-filter)