# Is there a way to block an angular service injection until the service's async data are loaded

Tags: angularjs, service, promise, inject

I have a 'userSessionDataService'. This fetches the user's details from the server (ONLY ONCE).

I want the user data to be accessible when the service is called, but without the need to call .then() on a promise.

From what I understand this is not supported by angular. The caller of the service must always use a promise to access data that were loaded asynchronously (e.g.through ajax).

Comment: I agree that this is not possible. I don't know that this is a design that you really want anyway--causing your application to block at a fundamental level waiting for an asynchronous resource.

Comment: I had the same issue.  I solved it and am working on my answer.  Give me a couple minutes.

Comment: Easier to provide this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/initialize-angularjs-service-with-asynchronous-data

Comment: What I did is different.  I store the user data in `localStorage` when they login in.  On startup, I check if it is in localStorage and it has not expired.  If it is missing or expired, I use `$location.path('/SignIn');` inside `module().run()`  If you are still interested I can cobble together how I do it in an answer.

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnson What I can understand from the link above is that I will need to use resolve in every route which requires userSessionDataService? Which means everywhere.

Comment: yes, that is the BIG downside of it.

Comment: in fairness though, you can just resolve in the routes that will be used at initialization.  I use two in my apps (loggedIn vs not loggedIn)

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnson I don't exactly get this. What if I am in anyView and user refreshes his browser? I want him to stay in the same page. In order for this to happen I need a mechanism to fetch again the session object, before route matches anyView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find useful to manually bootstrap like I did for localisation:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/GetResources",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            var mn = 'app';
            angular.module(mn).value('Resources', result);
            angular.bootstrap(document, [mn]);
        }
    });
});
```

Resources are always available this way:

```
angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope, Resources){
     $rootScope.resources = Resources;
});
```

Comment: I just wonder why such an initialization is not supported in angular lifecycle.

Comment: I like this answer.  I would only add that you can do something similar in `module().config()` and so have access to `$http` and the promise will be fulfilled by the time that `module().run()` is executed.

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnson is it possible that you post an answer with such a code?

Comment: Sure, give me a little bit so I can create a plunker too.

Comment: So I tried a solution using pure Angular and failed.  The task queue doesn't execute between Angular.module.run and loading of the controller. This solution is the closest I could get without interrupting the bootstrap process. Sorry :-(

Comment: Here is the plunkr I was messing with if you want to repost. http://plnkr.co/edit/aIMMoBd78hqTvtPeL2Nx?p=preview