# AngularJS: how to init resource with string first downloaded from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular app has some resources that I need to initialise with a string, e.g:

```
angular.module('client.core.resources')
   .factory('AuthenticationResource', ['$resource','ConstantValueService', function ($resource,ConstantValueService) {
  var authUrl = ConstantValueService.get('webApiUri') + '/api/authentication';
  return $resource(authUrl, {},
      {
        login: {
          method: 'POST',
          isArray: false
        },
        logout: {
          method: 'DELETE',
          isArray: false
        }
      });
}]);
```

Now I have some data in an external json file that contain values for a webApiUri.  I tried to do the following:

```
 angular.module('myapp').run(['$http',function($http){
      $http.get('client.json').success(function (settings) {
        ConstantValueService.setFields(settings);
    });
  }])
```

However, as it is an async process, tracing shows that in the above mentioned resource, authUrl gets initialised way before client.json is loaded. So in resource the authUrl = undefined.

I would like to know if there is a nice way to postpone initialising and running of the angular app until the `$http` promise is fulfilled.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with angular to give a full solution but your first code has a dependency on `ConstantValueService`. Make sure angular knows that it's a dependency and when it's _ready_ to be used (after `.setFields`)

Comment: Have you tried loading the client.json file with a script tag?  If the data is static and sitting in that file, you can load it as a script.

Comment: You could also use jQuery to load the data synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent summary of this topic in [this other StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/initialize-angularjs-service-with-asynchronous-data).

I made my own demo based on your particular problem, see the project in [GitHub](https://github.com/masa67/ng-manual-init). I based my solution to the proposal by JBCP, i.e., the manual initialization, as I thought that was closest to the spirit of your case.

Please read also what the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) says about this.