# How to integrate resource call with directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Basically, I have two directives:

```
angular.module("maineMap")
.directive("ngMap", ["APPCONFIG", "Map", function(config, Map){
       //D3 map drawing functionality based on data from $resource call
       return {
        restrict : "E",
        transclude : true,
        scope : {
            mapData : '='
        },
        link : function(scope, el, attrs){
                   }
        };
    }])
    .directive("donutChart", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        link : function(scope, el, attrs){
                    }
            }
    });
```

and a controller

```
angular.module("maineMap")
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope','Map', function($scope, Map{
    $scope.mapData = Map.mapData()  
                        .query();

    $scope.mapData.$promise.then(function(results){
        $scope.mapData = results;
        console.log($scope.mapData);
    });

}]);
```

where `Map` is a `$resource` implementation to get a JSON file.

My issue is that the directive functionality is executing prior to the controller call.  That is, I call upon several properties of `mapData` within the directives, and they are all returning undefined with corresponding error messages in the console.  However, shortly after the error printout, the data fetch from the `$resource` implementation executes and is printed to console.

Note that if I replace the `$promise` and depend solely on

```
$scope.mapData = Map.mapData()  
                        .query();
```

then I have `$scope.mapData` visible in the `<donut-chart>` directive, but not `<ng-map>`.

Given this kind of structure, how can I delay the directive functionality until after the controller loads the data?

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution for:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <outer>
      <inner></inner>
      <inner></inner>
    </outer>
</div>
```

would be:

1. compile (inner)
2. compile (inner)
3. compile (outer)
4. controller
5. controller (outer)
6. controller (inner)
7. link (inner)
8. controller (inner)
9. link (inner)
10. link (outer)

So, controller clearly sets the scope before linking of directives occurs. Unless, of course, the scope is set in an asynchronous function. But your directive should be able to handle `undefined` scope values since the directive doesn't (an probably shouldn't) care under which controller it's operating under unless it [`requires`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) it.

Comment: Thats the thing.. the scope value is set in an asynchronous function and the data fetched is integral to the directive.  If the directive doesn't have the data, it throws errors and doesn't do anything.

Comment: That doesn't look like a good design. A directive should be able to handle `undefined` values and should not make any assumptions about what the parent scope has or doesn't have.

Comment: Its a D3 app, which requires data to draw the svg paths.

Comment: @Jason, how does that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

I used [joakimbi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288468/214892) solution for this problem.  Specifically, I added a `ngRoute` dependency and use the `resolve` property to ensure that the promises enclosed would execute a data fetch prior to displaying a view.

Updated service:

```
angular.module("maineMap")
.factory("MapService", ["$http", "$log", "$q", "appConfig", function($http, $log, $q, appConfig){
    var mapPaths, mapPromise, 
        cityPositions, cityPromise;

    return {
        getMapPaths : function(){

            mapPromise = $http.get(appConfig.maineData)
                                .success(function(data){
                                    mapPaths = data;
                                });

            return {
                getData : function(){
                    return mapPaths;
                },
                setData : function(data){
                    mapPaths = data;
                },
                promise : mapPromise
            };
        },
        getCityPositions : function() { ... }
   };
}]);
```

Modified app initializer that defines the promise in the resolve property:

```
angular.module("maineMap", ["ngResource", "ngRoute", "configuration"])
.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "views/main.html",
        controller : "MapCtrl",
        resolve : {
            "MapData" : function(MapService){
                return MapService.getMapPaths().promise;
            },
            "CityData" : function(MapService){
                return MapService.getCityPositions().promise;
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

Modified controller, where the data fetch is loading prior to the view:

```
angular.module("maineMap")
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope','MapService', function($scope, MapService){
    $scope.mapData = MapService.getMapPaths().getData();
    $scope.cityData = MapService.getCityPositions().getData();
    $scope.currentCounty = {};
    console.log("MapData: " + $scope.mapData);
}]);
```

The result of this is that prior to the directive's tag being processed within the view template, a data fetch executes and saves the results on the scope, making it available to the directive.

Another option, proposed by [Martin Atkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20448708/214892), would have loaded the data into an `angular.constant()` variable.  Since I'm planning on extending this application for several views, the `ngRoute` combined with `resolve` promises was the appropriate solution.