# Angular get user object on full page refresh with jwt

Tags: ajax, angularjs, token, jwt

What is a proper way (best code organization) to get user object from JWT in storage on full page refresh (it requires new ajax request) ?

How can I perform an ajax request before my angular app's routing start?
Adding an extra request in resolve part on every route is bad (DRY). How I can simplify that?

Is an abstract view (using UI router) with resolve best solution?

Comment: This question seems to be opinion based on the fact that you are asking for the "best" way of doing something. That in mind, if you provided a few specific code examples it is possible that someone may have a suggestion based on those. Traditionally in angular you wouldn't load data before the SPA starts but instead via model binding in the controller. You might also look at using [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) in angular.

Comment: you have a few options for loading data before starting the angular app. See: [Initialize Angularjs Service with Asynchronous Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/initialize-angularjs-service-with-asynchronous-data)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to use ajax with jwt for user experience.
you can set your user object to $rootscope once then use in any route.

using resolve with ui-router is perfect way for your situation as i think .