# How to delay the instantiation of a factory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to define a simple factory that will be the entry point for a `$resource` definition for a given resource in my app (say `Post`). The problem is that the URL for `Post` depends on the user's organization, so it doesn't make sense (nor is it even possible) to instantiate the `Post` class until the user has signed in (eg, a url like `https://host.com/organizations/your-org/posts/:id`)

The controllers that depend on `Post` are all protected by login and so it should be OK (in theory) to define `Post` assuming the user has already logged in.

However I've found that simple requiring `Post` in *any* controller signature initializes the `Post` factory at bootstrap time.

```
angular.module('myapp.services', [])
.factory("Post", function($resource, Auth, $localStorage){
  return $resource(Auth.links.posts.href, {id: "@id"});
});
```

`Auth.links` is initialized after login, so bootstrapping the app when a user is logged out causes errors because `Auth.links` is null.

I've thought of 2 ways to deal with this, neither of which I'm really excited about:

1. Rewrite `Post` factory to return a promise that will be immediately resolved assuming you're logged in. But why create *another* callback when this should just work?
2. Make the initial `Post` factory a stub and then modify the `Auth.login()` method so that it overwrites the `Post` factory with the correct definition. This seems hacky and non-standard, and I've [read that trying to add services or factories after the app has been bootstrapped doesn't work properly (without some hacks)](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm).

Has anyone solved similar problems before? And/or do you recommend some particular approach? Thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

SOOOO apparently I had an `if` statement incorrect in my router that was defaulting logged-out users to a logged-in page, which was causing this whole mess.
Turns out that stuff *does* actually work how it's supposed to and my problem was coder error. Derp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize AngularJS service with asynchronous data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/initialize-angularjs-service-with-asynchronous-data)

Comment: Yeah I guess using `resolve` in the router is an OK option. It feels kinda icky to me, because I don't want to change the name of my factory to `PostFactory` or `PostModelAndPromise` or something like that but it's definitely a better option than other things I've come up with so far.

Comment: There are other answers in that post that might apply

Comment: That question in general is about running something as soon as possible, like before the app is bootstrapped. My question is about _delaying_ the instantiation of a factory until after login. Similar but unfortunately the answers in that question didn't seem applicable to me

Comment: You can initialise it manually using $injector : $injector.get('$log');

Comment: Something bizarre was going on yesterday. Now it's magically working, without code changes. I blame Gremlins.