# Wait until Object created - (JavaScript/AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory and a Controller.

#### Factory

```
vm.profiles = new ProfileFactory();
```

#### Controller

```
if (Object.keys(vm.profiles.items).length == 0) {
      vm.noProfiles = true;
}
```

I have a prototype nextPage() in the ProfileFactory -> vm.profiles Object.
This Method queries the backend. I want to set the vm.noProfiles Variable to true if there are no items in vm.profiles.items.

#### The Problem

It goes automatically inside the if statement, because the if doesn't wait until the item is populated through the prototype Method nextPage().

How can I force JavaScript to wait until it is populated?
Is there a better solution?

### //Edit

This ihere is part of the nextPage Method. Should I do the query in the controller and just return the promise from Restangular or $http?

```
// Get List of Posts
            Restangular.allUrl('user', ApiConfig.baseUrl + ':' + ApiConfig.port + '/users').getList(query)
                .then(function (items) {
                    //console.log(items);

                    if (items.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                            this.items.push(items[i]);
                        }
                        if (this.offset < items.meta.page_count) {
                            this.offset += 1;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    this.busy = false;
                }.bind(this));
```

Comment: I think this is a good use case for using Promises (ES6 ones or $q by angularjs). Promise will trigger a callback once the server responded to your request.

Comment: As @Shikloshi said you can check promises here because it's very good https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: And just another thing - it is consider a good practice to return promise from the rest service back to the controller.

Comment: @Shikloshi Should I do this without creating the object from the ProfileFactory, just call the rest service from the controller?

Comment: Maybe you could just wait for items being loaded first?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/angularjs-initialize-service-with-asynchronous-data

Comment: In case if you are lucky to be able to use ES6, `Object.observe(...)` might help you (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you can use it's [resolve feature](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) to specify what needs to be loaded before your controller ever becomes active.

There are two steps you need to take here:

1. Set up resolve in your route configuration.

   In the rout configuration for your controller, add the `resolve:` key with a function returning a promise for the items you want pre loaded before your controller is activated. Something along the lines of:

   ```
   $stateProvider.state('myState', {
       // ...
       resolve: {
           items: function(Restangular, ApiConfig /* add any other di's here */) {
               return Restangular.allUrl('user', ApiConfig.baseUrl + ':' +
                                          ApiConfig.port + '/users');
      }
   ```

   Now when this route is fired, your controller is not loaded until the promise returned by the function under the `items:` key is resolved. The response from this promise is available to your controller, you just need to di it by:
2. In your controller add the items to you di's in your controller definiton:

   ```
   angular
       .module('yourModuleName')
       .controller('YourControllerName', function(..., items) {
       // ...
       // items should hold the response from the promise returning function in 
       // route config
   });
   ```