# Dynamically invoking module.config() is blocked

Tags: angularjs

Rather than running config at the initial stage, I would like to config something at a later stage based on some information fetched from server like this:

```
$http.get(url)
.success( function(response){
    angular.module('MyApp').config(['$myServiceProvider', function( $myServiceProvider){
        $myServiceProvider.enableSomething(true); // delayed !!!
    }]);
});
```

However the running of the body of config() function is blocked until I loaded some lazy-loaded partial. Maybe a $compile() will trigger it.

I do not understand why it is like this and how to make the config() body invoked immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: Angular Prefixes $ and $$: To prevent accidental name collisions with your code, Angular prefixes names of public objects with $ and names of private objects with $$. Please do not use the $ or $$ prefix in your code.

Comment: @pat Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular-deferred-bootstrap module does that exactly : https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap

See : https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap#attach-constants-to-specific-modules

Also, this question offers other options : [AngularJS : Initialize service with asynchronous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/angularjs-initialize-service-with-asynchronous-data)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible in your scenario to use `$http` in a `module.run` call and configure your service in the `$http`'s success handler?

If it absolutely needs to happen before the `module.config`call, remove `ng-app` from your HTML and do the bootstrapping yourself by calling `angular.bootstrap` as outlined in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) after you have fetched the file.

As far as I'm aware, there's no way of *blocking* the configuration phase.