# How to access sub objects of an object returned by AngularJS data service inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

I have an angularjs data factory that makes a server call and sets the  returned data in the factory returned object like this

```
 angular.module('app').factory('DataService', function() {
        // Returning object
        return {
            data: {},
            isLoaded: false,
            getData:getdata

        };
        function getData() {
            var self  = this;
           //Some Ajax Call returns an 'dataObject'
           self.data = dataObject; //dataObject has a few subObjects and list
        }
 });
```

Now inside my angularjs controller I am making call to the DataService.getData() to make ajax call and hence set the returned dataObject within factoryobject 'data'

and I have declared it in controller like this

```
appV.data = DataService.data;
```

If I try to print it on console or access like this
console.log(appVm.data), I am able to access it, but if I try to access any subObjects like Ex - appVm.data.property1 or appVm.data.subObject1.subObject1.property, it gives undefined.

Can someone please explain why this behavior is occuring ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use promises: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: you may need to `resolve `method, load data before loading controller

Comment: can you show yur ajax call code.

Answer (score 0):

It is just example:

```
app.factory("messageService", function($q){
    return {
        getMessage: function(){
            return $q.when("Hello World!");
        }
    };
});
```

And now the routing configuration that will use the service in a resolve.

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
        }
    }
})
```

These link may help you:

[Link 1](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx),
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/angularjs-initialize-service-with-asynchronous-data?rq=1)