# Angular directives are being call before data/token throws error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, token

I have a service that will auth my user and get a token. I'm consuming it on the mainController which is appended to the body (index.html)

That should be the frist thing to do in my app.

In my index.html are 2 directives (which are consuming a service that needs that token)

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="row" ng-if="token">
   <div directive1></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" ng-if="token">
    <div directive2></div>   
  </div>
</body>
```

It throws an error because the token is not yet defined when the directives are used.

```
 angular.module('app').directive('directive1', function () {
  return {
  templateUrl: directive1.html,     
  controller: function (thingsService) {
        //
   }
 }
});
```

I've got a solution based on `ng-if == token` on html directive call (index.html)

This does the job, but I'm not really satisfied. Is there a better solution? I've seen a solution of watches already.

Comment: what if your directives take the token as a parameter (so that they are called when it changes) and don't throw error if the token is undefined (vs wrong) ?

Comment: Hum never thought that you. That could work. But would the directives wait for that parameter to be ready to use? I mean, wouldnt it be always undifined?

Comment: when is your token service called/your token generated ?

Comment: @Derlin, mainController calls a service that gets the token

Comment: @Derlin, yes It returns undifined when passing token as parameter

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is not better than the `ng-if`, but maybe cleaner. The idea is to pass the token to the directive as a parameter (instead of the service). The directive watches for changes on the token and react accordingly.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/3055/) demonstrating how to implement such service:

```
.directive('aDirective',
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: {
                token: '=', // <= declare a token parameter
            },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          var controllerOptions, options;
          $scope.$watch('token', function(value){
            // do stuff here
          });        
        }
      };
    }
  )
```

I also suggest you to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189057/2667536), which demonstrate how to wait for a condition/initialisation before loading an angular module. You could then first initialise your token, then load your module.